# Display in the admin panel if other user is logged in at that moment

Tags: php

I have this thing I want to create for known purposes. I'm making a website where users can sign up, sign in, have personalized experience etc. Long story short I'm going to have admin panel as well where I'll display users information, update upon request etc. I want to display either red or a green dot next to the user page in admin panel depending if they're online or offline. I honestly couldn't find any info about how this is done. To give you an idea this is what I want to do (and what I've tried):

```
$_SESSION['email'] = 'email@example.com';

if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
  echo ''.$_SESSION['email'].' is logged in';
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work. So I want to tell php I want to check if this email is logged in at the moment since I set **$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];** when the user logs in and display the green dot next to it. If anyone can help me out on this I'd appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each user has their own session variables. You'll need to save something in the database when an admin user logs in, and then this script can check the DB.

Comment: I have 50+ tabs open right now, some of which are from last week and I haven't touched them at all this week. Am I "online" with all of these still?

Comment: @ChrisHaas right, I get it but I want to create something like facebook active status where you can see if other users are logged in and are currently using facebook or not however in this case it will be only displayed in the admin panel.

Comment: Logged in/out is pretty easy. As Barmar noted, just log those very specific items, either on the user table itself, or in a dedicated log table (my preference). For "active", that's vague. If your users "do things" that get tracked in the database, you could log timestamps for that, too, and if "now - timestamp" is within a certain threshold (maybe 5 minutes) you could say they are "active". You could also have the client call home every _n_ seconds, optionally only while the window has focus.

Comment: I do it by loggin the time stamp into LastActive field in user table for each activity user performs and then while retrieving the user list I check if the LastActive has not elapsed more than 1 minute to see if the user is online and active. Let me know if you need code sample to help you do it.